# Multiple instances of GoogleApiClient with Nearby Messages API

Tags: android, eddystone, google-nearby

**What I'm doing :**

I'm using Eddystone with Google Nearby Messages API.

I'm connecting to Google API in onCreateView() to initiate the object and calling `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`
then in GoogleAPI's `onConnected()`, I'm calling `Nearby.Messages.subscribe()` for listening for messages.

As a result of this, mGoogleApiClient's "connected", "subscribed successfully" are occuring currently 3-4 times at same moment, as I see in Log.

***I want it to instantiate the `connect(), subscribe()` only once & avoid multiple connection to Google.***

In `onFound()` , I'm running `runOnUiThread(thread)` which *parses my json-string attachment, add to arraylist, add arraylist to custom adapter, set adapter to recyclerview*.

(Each Attachment which I'm processing in `onFound()` under `runOnUiThread()` :

```
{"Z":[{"a":"text","b":"text","c":"text","d":"text","e":"text","f":"text"
}]}
```

)

Question is,

**So, do I need really need to use `runOnUiThread()` which only allows me to set recyclerview adapter as LayoutManager as owner of child ? How else I can achieve the same ?**

**How do avoid multiple `connect()`, `subscribe()` instance ?**

**How to avoid duplicate attachments being shown in my list?**

**How to restore the recyclerView with custom adapter when `onResume()` ?**

Comment: create a base activity and do all subscription and connection in this activity. and use them where ever you want

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you call `GoogleApiClient#connect()` in `onStart()` and then call `GoogleApiClient#disconnect()` in `onStop()`. If you are calling `Nearby.Messages.subscribe()` in `onConnect()`, you'll end up subscribing every time the fragment is created (upon an orientation change, for example). For this reason, you should call `Nearby.Messages.unsubscribe()`in `onPause()`.

And yes, you do need to use `runOnUiThread()`, so you don't end up concurrently modifying resources.

I'm not sure what you mean by "which only allows me to set recyclerview adapter as LayoutManager as owner of child ". Can you clarify? In fact, could you please ask that as a separate question (it isn't good StackOverflow etiquette to lump multiple questions together).